# how to reference an agent in the pickup

Tags: anylogic

I want to move an agent in "queue3" to the position of "container" within a "pickup1" at pickup. What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to move the agents to the location of the container, you need:

- a wait block before queue3 (waitAgent)
- a wait block before pickup1 (waitContainer)

When a container arrives to waitContainer, you free the agents from waitAgent and all the agents use a moveTo block to move to the container.

Once they arrived to the container they will be in queue3

Once all the agents arrive to queue3, you free the container from waitContainer and it goes to pickup1.

This is the general way to do it with agents moving towards the container, but you will have to build the logic yourself...

If you allow the agents teleporting to the container the solution is different... but i assume you want to see them moving

Comment: Felipe, thank you for your quick response - that seems what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Pickup will "pick up" whatever it is linked to, in your case whoever waits at the exit of `queue3`.

If you want to manage *who* waits at that exit, you can either change the queuing from FIFO to something else via its properties. Or use a `Wait` block and extract agents manually into a queue ahead of `queue3`

Comment: Hi Ben my question may have been misleading/not well put. My intention is to "graphically move" (moveTo) the agent in 'queue3' to the location of the container in 'pickup1'.

Comment: I see, that is, in fact, a totally different question :)